# My Anaconda3 Prompt runs individual Python commands on the right path but runs programs on the wrong path

Tags: python, path, anaconda3

My inexperience has created a love-hate relationship between Anaconda3 and me. I've tried to diagnose the problem behind my programs' inability to locate modules installed in Anaconda. I have a file named TestPy.py:

```
import sys;
print(sys.path)

# When printing path in Anaconda Prompt:
# ''
# 'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\envs\\bulk\\python39.zip'
# 'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\envs\\bulk\\DLLs'
# 'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\envs\\bulk\\lib'
# 'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\envs\\bulk'
# 'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\envs\\bulk\\lib\\site-packages'

# When printing path in Program:
# 'C:\\Users\\evana\\Documents\\MyPrograms\\Python' <- directory of TestPy.py
# 'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip'
# 'C:\\Python311\\Lib'
# 'C:\\Python311\\DLLs'
# 'C:\\Python311'
# 'C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages'
```

I have documented the difference between when I enter the print(sys.path) command in the Anaconda3 Python console and when I run the same command inside of a program file (TestPy.py). I am very new to Python and computer science as a whole but I would appreciate any help!

As far as I understand, these differences in paths mean I am unable to import modules installed in my Anaconda environments as my programs run.

I have tried adding the first block of paths (in the same order) into my system path variables to force my programs to check my Anaconda environment temporarily named "bulk" for installed modules. Even still my programs do not check my Anaconda environment when importing. I am running these programs through the Anaconda3 Prompt as well. I also made sure to have singular backslashes when I added my path locations.

The same problem applies to the base Anaconda environment. The paths printed by the program are the same but the Anaconda3 Prompt prints this:

```
''
'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\python39.zip'
'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\DLLs'
'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\lib'
'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3'
'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages'
'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32'
'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib'
'C:\\Users\\evana\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'
```

I am afraid to delete my installed version of Python (version 3.11) or its system path but I have read on Anaconda's website this could be a confounding variable.

I have used MSYS2 to install C++ compilers but `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` runs on Python 3.10 (or so I am assuming by the Python file names in the directory) and none of the path names printed by the program are Python 3.10 but 3.11. If I am not mistaken, this suggests MYSY2 is not conflicting with the Anaconda path.

I would be happy to show any additional information necessary to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: How are you running `TestPy.py` so that it prints out the wrong `sys.path`?

Comment: I run Windows 11 and I boot up "Anaconda Prompt (anaconda3)." I then enter "cd C:\\Users\\evana\\Documents\\MyPrograms\\Python" followed by "py TestPy.py"

Comment: SOLUTION: Just from the question you asked I figured out "py TestPy.py" is not the same as "python TestPy.py". To run a program in an Anaconda environment, use "python TestPy.py" and not "py TestPy.py". I have been trying to figure this out for HOURS... and its just changing one word in my command... Thanks!